# Why does only the first regex work properly?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was testing regex in javascript:

```
    var a = prompt("Input: ")
    var t = /I AM (.*)|MY NAME IS (.*)/
    if(t.test(a)) {
    b = "HI " + t.exec(a)[1]
    alert(b)
    }
```

And if you input "I AM BOB" you get "HI BOB", and if you input "MY NAME IS BOB" you get "HI undefined", when I put "I AM (.*)" second in the regex then it would result in undefined as well.

So why does this regex work completely in the if statement but only the first half in the exec()? And how could I fix it?

Ps(Using exec(a)[0] just returns "HI MY NAME IS BOB")

Comment: So `exec(a)[0]` worked?  Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @Scott Hunter No because it is only supposed to return the name and the word hi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using parens around the `|` operator and factor out the `(.*)` capture group. You can make the OR group a non-capturing group with `?:`:

```
var a = prompt("Input: ")
var t = /(?:I AM|MY NAME IS) (.*)/
if(t.test(a)) {
    b = "HI " + t.exec(a)[1]
    alert(b)
}
```

EDIT: The reason your original code fails is that with `"MY NAME IS BOB"`, the second capture group matches so you would need to use `t.exec(a)[2]` to get `"HI BOB"` as an alert.

P.S. To avoid doing the match twice (once for `t.test(a)` and once for `t.exec(a)`) you can do this:

```
var a = prompt("Input: ")
var t = /(?:I AM|MY NAME IS) (.*)/
var result = t.exec(a) // will be null whenever t.test(a) would return false
if(result) {
    b = "HI " + result[1]
    alert(b)
}
```

Comment: I thought it might be something like that! But on its own that would not have helped me but thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

RegExp.prototype.exec returns an array containing the matched text and then one item for each capturing parentheses.

- On "I AM BOB":

  - `t.exec(a)` returns `["I AM BOB", "BOB", undefined]`. It returns undefined because the second capturing parentheses did not captured anything.

---

- On "MY NAME IS BOB":

  - `t.exec(a)` returns `["MY NAME IS BOB", undefined, "BOB"]`

To fix it you would have to access `t.exec(a)[2]`. Ted Hopp's solution to fix this is what you want to do though.